# can't change the CSS of the bootstrap tooltip "arrow"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want it to be gray, just like the color I set here:

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
  color: #333;
}
```

but the color of the "arrow" portion of the tooltip reverts doesn't change.

[image]

I tried:

```
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #b9b9b9;
}
```

and

```
.tooltip-arrow {
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
}
```

to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe there's a `::before` or `::after` pseudo element somewhere?

Comment: Did you try `.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow`?

Comment: @j08691no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the CSS to class `.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow` will resolve the issue, as shown in the below-working snippet.

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.example-tooltip .tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip top" role="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner"> Tooltip on the top </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not looking to make HTML changes. I have thousands of places in my code where the bootstrap tooltip is used. I just need to know how to change the arrow color, simple as that. Seems like nothing I try works. I just need a simple CSS only  change.

Comment: it's a demo html to show the output, ignore it, can u try the css in your code and see if it works there :)

Comment: by seeing the question(attaching a image) we can only guess, that might be the issue?, can u share the bootstrap version, a small working or reproducable issue so that some body can analyse and help u with it

Answer (score 0):

The arrow of the tooltip comes to css as :after and is generally border value.

You have to use

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner::after {
  border-color: #b9b9b9 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, no effect. tooltip arrow still cyan...